An isekai manga where the MC is abandoned and the bullies were appointed as heroes
The bullies ruled the world and raped demons, but the MC is still there fighting them one by one. It's not Isekai NTR, although it's as grim as that. I think there was this companion that gave him powers.

Some possibilities at https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-ntr-nakama-ni-barezu-ni-harem-wo-light-novel/recommendations but I can't really research that where I am.
